# How to add double quotes to CC Page Label?

Tags: b2b-commerce, cloudcraze

I'm trying to add a page label in CC Page Labels that says

```
Set up your URL under "My Account."
```

however it displays as

`Set up your URL under &quot;My Account.&quot;`

I've tried using two single quotes, using a backslash `\"`, and adding `&quot;` directly in the `valueRT`and none of those worked. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

below answer worked for me:
`<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!PageLabelValue ['Welcome_Text']}"/>`